# Unexpected error with attachments in Slack API

Tags: php, laravel, attachment, slack, slack-api

I am trying to attach multiple images in Slack API and using Laravel's Slack Notification API. It works fine for a limited number of attachments, but when I try to attach around 100 images then it throws the following error:

[image]

Why might this be happen? I tried to debug it but nothing worked out.

Comment: It is right in the error message.....

Comment: @KurtFriars how we can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot fix this error. The *Slack* hook is rejecting your request with the error:

```
"419 Request Entity Too Large" ... "too_many_attachments".
```

You can have a [maximum of 20 attachments](https://api.slack.com/legacy/interactive-message-field-guide#:%7E:text=Provide%20a%20JSON%20array%20of,no%20more%20than%2020%20attachments.). If you have 100 attachments, you will need to send 5 messages.